# Pinging IP or HOSTNAME with Xamarin from Lava.Lang.Process

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying this code and it returns always `TTL Expired` even if the ip or hostname is `unreachable` , `timeout` or any other diferrent problem :

`using System.Net.NetworkInformation;`

```
PingReply Reply = await pingo.SendPingAsync(text_ip.Text, 4000, buffer, options);
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        switch (Reply.Status)
        {
            case IPStatus.Success:

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;

            case IPStatus.TimedOut:

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;

            case IPStatus.TimeExceeded:

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;

            case IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable:


               Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;

            case IPStatus.DestinationNetworkUnreachable:

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;

            case IPStatus.DestinationUnreachable:

                Toast.MakeText(Activity, Reply.Status.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;
        }
```

I found a bug at 
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/Ping.cs (line 339)

and reported it at : 
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53284

That calls the system ping command and checks the exit code:

```
if (!ping.WaitForExit (timeout) || (ping.HasExited && ping.ExitCode == 2))
    status = IPStatus.TimedOut;
else if (ping.ExitCode == 0)
    status = IPStatus.Success;
else if (ping.ExitCode == 1)
    status = IPStatus.TtlExpired;
```

> So TTL expired is set when there was no timeout, no error or success (exit code 2 or 0), and the exit code was 1.
>
> If ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with `code 1`. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with `code 1`. On other error it exits with `code 2`. Otherwise it exits with `code 0`. This makes it possible to use the exit code to see if a host is alive or not.
>
> So a return value of 1 indicates that no response has been received (for various reasons) and the Mono implementation sets the `TTL expired` status in this case. I would expect that a time out status would be returned in such cases. But it seems that the `timeout` detection of the Mono implementation is not triggered here (e.g. because the ping command exits upon on it's own timeout before).
>
> So there is other possible solutions:
>
> **To treat a `TTL expired` as host not alive (but this will then ignore real `TTL expired` detections)**

**Anyway can somebody show another way to do this for example :**

```
try 
{
    Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
    int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
    ipProcess.destroy();

    if(exitValue == 0)
    {
        // Success
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Failure
    }
} 
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And to get from this `Time in ms` , `Ttl value` , `Statistics`, `Packet Loss`, `Received Packets` , `Transmited Packets` and other information from the process shell for each ping secuence ?

**UPDATE**

How to implement it for this purpose :

```
public async void add_data(string adresa)
    {
        await Task.Delay(ping_interval);
        if (sekuenca < sekuenca_db && nderprit == false)
        {
            try
            {
                PingReply Reply = await pingo.SendPingAsync(text_ip.Text, timeout, buffer, options);
                switch (Reply.Status)
                {
                    case IPStatus.Success:

                        string sekuena = sekuenca.ToString();
                        mdata.Add(new data() { titulli = "From : " + Reply.Address.ToString(), sekuenca = "Secuenca : " + sekuena + ",", ttl = "TTL : " + Reply.Options.Ttl.ToString() + ",", madhesia = "Send : " + Reply.Buffer.Length.ToString() + " bytes", koha = "Time : " + Reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms" });
                        mAdapter.NotifyItemInserted(mdata.Count() - 1);
                        if (ndaluar == false)
                        {
                            mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(mdata.Count() - 1);
                        }
                        time = time + Reply.RoundtripTime;
                        koha.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Reply.RoundtripTime));
                        add_data(text_ip.Text);
                        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the ping time using the OS' buit-in `ping` command is starting a process, reading its output and *parse that data*.

So the steps necessary to take:

- Create a `System.Diagnostics.Process`
- Set up its StartInfo-Parameters correctly
- Redirect its StandardOutput
- Read the output from the StreamReader you can access into a string
- Parse that string. For this, you need knowledge on how the resulting output is being laid out

For the first parts (until the string-thing), your code could look like this:

```cs
Process P = new Process();
P.StartInfo.FileName = "ping";
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c 3 8.8.8.8"; // Take 3 samples to 8.8.8.8
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

string readData = "";
if (P.Start())
    readData = P.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // This will also wait for the process to at least close its stdout
Console.Write(readData.ToString()); // Doing this, you will see how the output looks like
```

After this, you would have an output like this in `readData`:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 3016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.910/13.926/13.951/0.010 ms
```

All you need to do now, is parsing the relevant part you are interested in. I recommend using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` to achieve this. I assume you are interested in the average round-trip time. In this case you would want to perform the following steps:

- Ignore everything but the last line containing the statistics
- Extract the value you are interested in
- In case you need the value being a `float` (or `double`), parse that value

  ```
      List<string> Lines = new List<string>(readData.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n'));

      while (Lines.Count > 0 && !Lines[0].StartsWith("---"))
          Lines.RemoveAt(0);

      // Here, we either have an empty list or a list starting with the line --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
      float avgPingTime = 0;
      if (Lines.Count > 2)
      {
          // Our important line is now Lines[2], the one starting with "rtt"
          Match M = Regex.Match(Lines[2], @"^rtt [^0-9]*([\d][^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^ ]+) ms$");
          if (M != null && M.Success) // A match has indeed been found
          {
              string avgPingString = M.Groups[2].Value;

              // Now parse that value
              float.TryParse(avgPingString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out avgPingTime);
          }
      }

      if (avgPingTime > 0)
      {
          // We parsed the value correctly here
      }
  ```

If you, however, are interested in the stats of each line *before* the statistic, you need a different approach:

> 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=13.9 ms

There are `n` of those lines, all of them *before* the line starting with `---`:

```
List<string> Lines = new List<string>(readData.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n'));

while (Lines.Count > 0 && !Lines[0].StartsWith("---"))    
{
    Match M = Regex.Match(Lines[0], @"^[\d]+ bytes from ([^:]+): [^ ]+ ttl=([\d]+) time=([^ ]+) ms");

    if (M != null && M.Success)
    {
        string IP = M.Groups[1].Value;
        string TTL = M.Groups[2].Value;
        string timeStr = M.Groups[3].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Ping to {0} took {2} ms with a ttl of {1}", IP, TTL, timeStr));
        // Parsing the timeStr will work the same way as above
    }

    Lines.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but how to use regex to read for example ttl , time , bytes for each line in asyncronous ... ? Can you help ?

Comment: I guess this could help

Comment: Thank you so much bro , i will try to implement in my app. :)

Comment: i suggest you to post this at the documentation : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/9434/ping-icmp#t=201703191559045383672

Comment: I don't think that would make sense, because this is not the way a ping is _intended_ to be. It is just the way that works for you, because you didn't want the sandbox-overhead ping times.

Comment: hmmm , maybe but this solve the real pinging from Mono System Libraries... And i think mono should make something to repair this overhead ...

Comment: One last question that im facing about this : `P.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` wait for a process to finish than process the array of strings. but how to process strings in real time line for line till the end ? And if for example i ping with unlimited count how to stop the process at certain time and display the statistics too ? Thanks for your time anyway ....

Comment: `ReadToEnd` does not wait for the __process__ to __finish__, but for its __standard output__ to __close__ (that's a difference, although not a big one in that particular case). I would suggest to make this a different question.

Comment: Done :D : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892207/how-to-read-output-from-process-line-per-line-an-stop-at-certain-time