# How to read from output in real time and stop at certain time if needed

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

so , i have this working code to display ping and statistics from `System.Diagnostics.Process`

```
Process P = new Process();
P.StartInfo.FileName = "ping";
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c 3 8.8.8.8"; // Take 3 samples to 8.8.8.8
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

string readData = "";
if (P.Start())
    readData = P.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // This will also wait for the  process to at least close its stdout
Console.Write(readData.ToString()); // Doing this, you will see how the
```

and i process the string in this way :

```
List<string> Lines = new List<string>(readData.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n'));

while (Lines.Count > 0 && !Lines[0].StartsWith("---"))    
{
    Match M = Regex.Match(Lines[0], @"^[\d]+ bytes from ([^:]+): [^ ]+ ttl=([\d]+) time=([^ ]+) ms");

    if (M != null && M.Success)
    {
        string IP = M.Groups[1].Value;
        string TTL = M.Groups[2].Value;
        string timeStr = M.Groups[3].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Ping to {0} took {2} ms with a ttl of {1}", IP, TTL, timeStr));
        // Parsing the timeStr will work the same way as above
    }

    Lines.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

`ReadToEnd();` wait until the standart output is closed and then process the string.

My question is how to process the string line per line in real time and how to stop the process in certain time and to get the statistics too in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.StreamReader` has a method called `ReadLine` which would be what you want to use:

```
if (P.Start()){
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
    while(!P.HasExited){
        readData = P.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); // This will wait for the next line to be output completely

        Match M = Regex.Match(Lines[0], @"^[\d]+ bytes from ([^:]+): [^ ]+ ttl=([\d]+) time=([^ ]+) ms");

        if (M != null && M.Success)
        {
            string IP = M.Groups[1].Value;
            string TTL = M.Groups[2].Value;
            string timeStr = M.Groups[3].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Ping to {0} took {2} ms with a ttl of {1}", IP, TTL, timeStr));
        }


        if (endTime > DateTime.Now)
            P.Kill();
    }
}
```

I introduced a variable called `endTime` that gets initialized with a time 5 seconds in the future, and when that time has been reached, the process gets killed causing your loop to terminate because `P.HasExited` now became `true`.

Comment: hmmm , what to say ... It's working correctly again ! :D :D

Comment: Glad I could have helped :)

Comment: Not just helped , today you have saved me from a lot of days of research and failed of testing and testing for some days without a solution. Do stack have opsion to add member in the favorite list ? :D :D :D :P :P

Comment: That's a good question for meta :D, I really don't know the answer

Comment: hahaha , finally found something that in my questions you dont know. i need to go now to continue my work. Have a nice time bro. bye , see you around here :D

Comment: hello there ... the only "small" problem that i have with that implementation is that when the process stop it don't show the statistics part. how to make this work when i stop the process to display the statistics too ?

Comment: i have question about that :D : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905673/how-to-stop-a-process-from-system-diagnostics-process-and-get-the-statistics-in